# How to move items between two components in react

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to transfer an item from one list to the next, along with it's object ID so i will be able to delete it after. Currently it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to select the object and move it to the delete panel with that information (both panels are just panel components from bootstrap). I tried using the checkboxes (shown below), but I wasn't able to select the value of the list group (also a bootstrap component) to pass it to the next panel.

The first panel get's passed the organizations from the database, into this.props, but the second I was just going to use an object that I would add to when the button on the first panel was clicked and pass that object into this.props.

Is there a best practice way to do this? Any help on solutions would be great. Right now the remove part is just static and doesn't actually do anything. I'm new to react and one way binding, but I feel like something that seems this simple shouldn't have me stumped like this.

Comment: Each of your table components manages its own data model right? Could you not add a function in the component called transferPropAtIndex(index, component) and then in that function remove the value at the given index in the local model and pass it to the props in the input component to update its own local data model....thats just a thought, hope you can get this working..

Comment: That sounds like it would work great. My question is, how do I get the value of the selected components then in react when using a third party tool like bootstrap?

Comment: Would you not create an onClick function that selected the active dom node upon click, from which you could retrieve the value from the data model?

Comment: You could create a temp model to which has the values appended for each box ticked and then pass that to your other component

Comment: I get an undefined error on this.onClick ('this' is undefined) with that. onClick={this.addToDeleteTable} is the syntax I used. Also, would I just say activeDomNode.getValue() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maintain an array like `organizationIdsToDelete` or even `organizationsToDelete` that gets added to when you select organizations to be deleted. Then pass the original organizations list to the first component as you are now, and pass the filtered list of organizations to delete to the second component.